# Ubuntu 18.04.1 can't connect to network

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, internet, laptop

At some point after I rebooted my laptop, it became unable to connect to both wired and wireless networks, though it detects their presence . If I try to connect, it asks password then starts endless process of connection. Password is correct, I checked it at least thrice. Before that reboot I could connect to wi-fi. What should I do?

Comment: can you post the output of `ifconfig -a`, `arp -a` and `lspci`?

Comment: No, I don't have computer available, can't attach file, nor can I send it from smartphone

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RFXs6D22bveerQvAb7DrTE9XoI24Cz5-/view?usp=drivesdk here is a link to output of given commands

Comment: It looks like your wireless interface is autoconfiguring for ipv6. Open your dropdown menu (top right of the screen by default) > click your wifi > settings > and finally click the cogwheel on the connection you're trying to use. Click the ipv4 tab and confirm that it's either set to automatic, or is configured correctly. Then check the ipv6 tab and ensure that that's also automatic or turned off (if you're on an ipv4 network).

Comment: Everything just as you've said. IPv4 is automatic (DHCP) and IPv6 is automatic. Please note that I use MATE, so some GUI involving instructions given may vary